# How to change the order of the code in an object?

Tags: javascript

I created a chessboard and used a singleton pattern.

```
Board = function(){ 
  var self = this;

  self.fillBoard = function(){
    for (var x = 0; x < self.x; x++){
      self.board[x] = [];

      for (var y = 0; y < self.y; y = y + 2){
        x%2 ? self.board[x][y] = 1 : self.board[x][y] = 0;
      }

      for (var y = 1; y < self.y; y = y + 2){
        x%2 ? self.board[x][y] = 0 : self.board[x][y] = 1;        
      }     
    }
  }

  self.x = 8; 
  self.y = 8; 
  self.board = [];
  self.fillBoard();

  self.outputBoard = function(){
    for (var x = 0; x < self.x; x = x + 1){
      for (var y = 0; y < self.y; y = y + 1){
        if(self.board[x][y] == 1){
          $('#board').append('<div class="board_cell" style="left: ' + x * 40 + 'px; top: ' + y * 40 + 'px"></div>');
        };
      }
    }   
  }
}

Board.getInstance = function(){
    if(!this.instance){
        this.instance = new this();
    }
    return this.instance;
};


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ init
$(document).ready(function(){
  board1 = Board.getInstance();
  board1.outputBoard();

  board2 = Board.getInstance();
  board2.outputBoard(); 

  console.log(board1 == board2);
});
```

But, the init block for object board:

```
self.x = 8; 
self.y = 8; 
self.board = [];
self.fillBoard();
```

is below then `self.fillBoard()`

I need move the init block upper:

```
Board = function(){ 
  var self = this;

  self.x = 8; 
  self.y = 8; 
  self.board = [];
  self.fillBoard();

  self.fillBoard = function(){
    for (var x = 0; x < self.x; x++){
      self.board[x] = [];

      for (var y = 0; y < self.y; y = y + 2){
        x%2 ? self.board[x][y] = 1 : self.board[x][y] = 0;
      }

      for (var y = 1; y < self.y; y = y + 2){
        x%2 ? self.board[x][y] = 0 : self.board[x][y] = 1;        
      }     
    }
  }

  ..............
  ...........
```

But the console output follows the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: self.fillBoard is not a function

ps: codepen is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RraydM

Comment: Obviously it isn't, what do you expect??! You call the function and then define it. You guess the result?

Comment: When you call `self.fillBoard();`, you have not yet defined the `function`...

Comment: Why do you not declare it as part of the prototype?

Comment: @epascarello They are probably following a tutorial and don't really know how to code at all. I didn't learn what a prototype was for a pretty long time.

Answer (score -1):

`self.fillBoard =...` defines the function. Before that point it does not exist.

`self.fillBoard();` calls the function. If the function does not exist when it is called you will get an exception. Go fix this just move the code up like you did but move the `self.fillBoard();` function call to below the `self.fillBoard =...` definition.

This would work...

```
Board = function(){ 

  var self = this;

  self.x = 8; 
  self.y = 8; 
  self.board = [];

  self.fillBoard = function(){
    for (var x = 0; x < self.x; x++){
      self.board[x] = [];

      for (var y = 0; y < self.y; y = y + 2){
        x%2 ? self.board[x][y] = 1 : self.board[x][y] = 0;
      }

      for (var y = 1; y < self.y; y = y + 2){
        x%2 ? self.board[x][y] = 0 : self.board[x][y] = 1;        
      }     
    }
  }

  self.fillBoard();

  ..............
  ...........
```

Comment: thanks, but the initialization code is scattered throughout the facility. if the object is 10 times larger, it is difficult to read it

Comment: You cannot call the function before it has been defined. You don't really have any other options besides completely rewriting things to use a more object oriented aproach.

Answer (score -1):

Use the prototype for methods on an object:

```
Board = function(){ 
  var self = this;

  self.x = 8; 
  self.y = 8; 
  self.board = [];
  self.fillBoard();
}

Board.prototype.fillBoard = function(){
  for (var x = 0; x < this.x; x++){
    this.board[x] = [];

    for (var y = 0; y < this.y; y = y + 2){
      x%2 ? this.board[x][y] = 1 : this.board[x][y] = 0;
    }

    for (var y = 1; y < this.y; y = y + 2){
      x%2 ? this.board[x][y] = 0 : this.board[x][y] = 1;        
    }     
  }
};
```

And for a bit of optimization:

```
Board.prototype.fillBoard = function(){
  for (var x = 0; x < this.x; x++){
    this.board[x] = [];

    for (var y = 0; y < this.y; y = y + 2){
      this.board[x][y] = x%2 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    for (var y = 1; y < this.y; y = y + 2){
      this.board[x][y] = x%2 ? 0 : 1;
    }     
  }
};
```

Comment: It wasn't me but I assume it was because prototypes seem way above this askers current skill level

Comment: `x%2 ? this.board[x][y] = 0 : this.board[x][y] = 1;` does not work without brackets.